# Lisp-like (prefix) output for the Reduce/Redlog computer algebra system

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

This is about the Reduce computer algebra system ([reduce-algebra.com](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/)).

I can print expressions from Reduce (and Redlog) into Reduce input format, e.g. `(c < 0 or b > 0)` using `off nat$`. I would like instead to obtain Lisp-like syntax, e.g. `(or (< c 0) (> b 0))`.

Is there a Reduce package that does this?

(Ok, I can always implement a separate parser and printer.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no package that does that, I implemented a simple parser and pretty-printer to convert to the appropriate syntax.